# Strange Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can't understand why the behavior is different.
In this version everything works as expected:

```
const debug = require("debug")("m");

const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        reject("promise rejected");
    }, 1000);
});

promise.then(
    v => {
        debug("resolve", v);
    },
    e => {
        debug("reject", e);
    },
);
```

Put a catch handler instead of reject handler:

```
const debug = require("debug")("m");

const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        reject("promise rejected");
    }, 1000);
});

promise.then(v => {
    debug("resolve", v);
});

promise.catch(e => {
    debug("catch: ", e);
})
```

works the same, but nodejs warning UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning. How to understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the key things about `then` and `catch` is *they create new promises*. (See [the Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/#the-then-method)* and [the JavaScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-promise.prototype.then) ["NewPromiseCapability" is the spec's way of saying "create a new promise"].) The promise the `then` handler in your second example is creating is rejected because its underlying promise is rejected, and that rejection is never handled.

The usual way to do it with `catch` would be a chain:

```
promise
    .then(v => {
        debug("resolve", v);
    })
    .catch(e => {
        debug("catch: ", e);
    });
```

That way, there is no unhandled rejection (and errors thrown in the `then` callback, if any, are propagated as a rejection to the `catch`).

---

* Promises/A+ allows `then` to return the same promise provided the implementation meets all the other requirements, but JavaScript's Promises don't.

Comment: Thanks. I found in "the Promises/A+ spec": 2.2.7.4 If onRejected is not a function and promise1 is rejected, promise2 must be rejected with the same reason as promise1.